# PHP, how to effectively use the functions in a class

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, class

I am using codeigniter framework. let say i had controller class named myclass, this class have a function that i want to access from another controller class.

I got troubled when access the function from another controller class, i cant create an instant of this myclass class, it say class 'myclass' not found. i dont want to use include 'myclass.php'; because class myclass have __constructor method, i afraid the content inside __constructor method will conflict with another __constructor.

what the best solution for my case?

Thanks

Comment: You will not have a conflict between constructor functions. Constructor functions will not automatically be called from including a file that defines a class. Constructor functions are called for the object upon instantiation. As long as your classes have different names you're fine.

Comment: Can you make the method static?

Comment: @Mari thanks for your reply, is include a file in every controller a best practice?.

Comment: @YasenZhelev , thanks for your reply. because my method have $this->load->model(); it show an error saying fatal error: using $this when not in object context

Comment: @stacheldraht27 in that case it can not be defined as static. CodeIgniter should have some way of automatically loading your custom classes. Did you try googling that? http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/autoloader.html

Comment: @YasenZhelev thanks ^^, sorry i thought codeigniter didnt have restriction between class controller. would you mind to retype your comment as an answer, so i can give the mark

Comment: My opinion I would use helper for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter framework has a way to automatically loading your custom classes. Look here: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/autoloader.html

Just make it possible for the framework to auto-load your class(es) and the problem is solved.